# Defining a function (or inverse) in terms of abstract properties

Tags: function-construction

Let's say I have a function $f$ and it's inverse $f^{-1}$

Say I don't know how to define either explicitly but I know one thing, and that is that $f$ is it's own inverse.

$$f( f(x) ) = x$$

Mathematica is quite capable of manipulating expressions where functions are only referred to by name, but I wish it to also use the above information when doing so.

How do I define such to Mathematica?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just this:

```
f[f[x_]] := x
```

Whenever `f[f[something]]` is encountered, it's replaced by `something`.

```
f[1]
(* f[1] *)

f[f[1]]
(* 1 *)

f[f[f[1]]]
(* f[1] *)
```

`f[f[x_]] := x` is a rule to replace `f[f[x_]]` by `x` whenever this pattern occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
f[x_] := x^2;

fInverse[y_] := Solve[f[x] == y, x]

fInverse[y]
```

{{x -> -Sqrt[y]}, {x -> Sqrt[y]}}

```
f[fInverse[x]]
```

(*
{{(x -> 0)^2}, {(x -> 1)^2}}
*)

Or

```
x /. f[fInverse[x]][[2, 1, 1]]
```

(*
1
*)

(There is no unique inverse when $x^2 = (-x)^2$.)

but you can try the above with `f[x_]:= 3 x + 8`, for example.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^2$ is not its own inverse.